# Philosophical Interpretation of String Theory

Tags: string-theory, theory-of-everything

I want to know whether [string theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory) is supposed to describe the world **exactly**, or whether it's just an **approximation** of some more fundamental theory. Is it similar to how the wave-equation approximates a rubber-band undergoing small vibrations?

Where could I read some string theorists' views on the relation of mathematics to the real world?

Comment: Re: *describes the world exactly* - That's what we cannot ever know for sure for *any* theory, and that's what the [scientific method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method) is all about.

Comment: Ofcourse we cannot know anything for sure, but we can ask and reason and practioners in the field must surely have developed some viewpoints on it.

Comment: I'm kinda curious why you think that the string theorists have a different view of the relation of mathematics to the real world than not string theorists.

Comment: Because string theory is about the relation of mathematics to the real world.

Comment: @user41404: you could really say that about all of physics.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer But normal physics is just an approximation to a TOE. If string theory is right, then all other physics is just an approximation to string theory. The question is if string theory is any different.

Comment: @user41404: it's still an application of math to describe the world, and before it was known that GR and QFT were inconsistent, it was possible to imagine that you could construct all of nature by applying the two side-by-side.  I think you're putting too much stock in the popular science phrase "theory of everything"

Comment: This is a great question. Where does ST fit into conventional theories of the philosophy and history of science, or the scientific method? 

Rightly or wrongly, ST is mired in philosophy of science questions - Does it make predictions? Is it falsifiable? Is it just mathematics? ST is not a theory like any other; it challenges our ideas about science.

The comments so far neglect this.

Comment: @innisfree: "ST is not a theory like any other; it challenges our ideas about science." May I ask how you come to this conclusion? The only real difference between string theory and GR or QFT is that it contains much more than these two frameworks, and that it allows one to address deeper questions, which is due to its more fundamental nature. How does this challenge anything we know about science?

Comment: @FredericBrünner I said that ST challenges our ideas about science, i.e., our conception of science: How are scientific theories developed? Why do we believe in particular theories? What is the role of experiments in science? Can you see, or at least acknowledge, that ST raises those questions?

Comment: @innisfree: The development of scientific theories is motivated both by experimental input and conceptual issues. Since experimental evidence for string theory might lie beyond our current technological capabilities (keyword: Planck scale), conceptual questions naturally play a bigger role (think quantum gravity, grand unification). While I acknowledge that people do raise those questions in the context of string theory, their justification is questionable. These issues are hyped especially on the level of popular science, but there is little actual scientific value to them.

Comment: @innisfree no it does not. There is absolutely nothing about String theory that contradicts the scientific method as it has always been applied for centuries. I agree with Frederic Brünner. The hype in popular media channels of such philosophical misunderstandings singling out string theory, claiming that there it is something wrong with it (in the worst cases they say not science etc), and so on is very unfortunate to say the least. The damage done to fundamental physics by such bad "science reporting" is already observable at a level of more than 5 sigma, in particular in the US...

Comment: Why has this question not been closed before the bounty? "How to explain all the mathematical structure that arises in string theory?" Can it be any more broad?

Comment: Related meta post: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6224/2451

Comment: I have edited it now to accomodate the meta post.

Comment: What happened to the bounty on this question? It still had days to run.

Comment: @MitchellPorter See the meta question.

Comment: @Dilaton you've closed a relatively dialectic exchange with a rant. Zzz

Answer (score 2):

(edit: note that I was responding here to an [earlier version of the question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/136604/2) which was somewhat different)

I think aspects of this question are a bit too broad and philosophical--asking "How to explain all the mathematical structure that arises in string theory?" reminds me of Wigner's essay puzzling about the question of ["The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in the Natural Sciences"](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~matc/MathDrama/reading/Wigner.html)--but as to the question of whether a completed version of superstring theory might still be an approximation, I can think of two reasons to suspect it wouldn't be:

1. Any quantum theory such as superstring theory should include the [Pauli exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle), which says that for any [fermion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermion) particle (a particle whose spin is an odd number times 1/2, like 1/2, 3/2, 5/2 etc.), only one can occupy a given state at the same time. And a "state" is defined by the values of some set of quantum-mechanical [observables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable), which include position, linear momentum, angular momentum, and spin. The exclusion principle implies that if there were any further undiscovered but in-principle-measurable properties of an electron, *we should already know about it*, because this would imply for example that more than two electrons would be able to occupy the lowest orbital of a Hydrogen atom (which puts them in the same quantum state for all the known observables except spin, and there are only two possible states for the spin observable of an electron). This does not imply that any quantum theory that includes electrons is exact rather than approximate, since the theory might fail to incorporate some *other* particles or fields, but it does at least imply that for any given fermion particle, the particle can't have additional bells and whistles that help determine its behavior that we might discover in the future, not unless the basic structure of quantum mechanics is badly wrong (and this doesn't rule out the idea of 'hidden' variables determining electrons' behavior that would be *in principle* impossible to measure--such variables appear in certain ["interpretations"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics) of quantum mechanics such as [Bohmian mechanics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-bohm/), but it seems like more of a metaphysical postulate than a physical one since they would remain forever impossible to measure and hidden from view).
2. There are some strong arguments from considerations of the [thermodynamics of black holes](http://www.physics.ucdavis.edu/Text/Carlip.html#thermo) that any future theory of [quantum gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gravity) (which string theory aims to be) must include the [Bekenstein bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound). The Bekenstein bound states that there is an absolute upper limit to the number of distinct physical states that a region with a given volume and total energy can possibly be in. This implied that if you had a theory whose collection of basic entities (strings, branes, whatever) and their observables predicted that number of possible states in such a region, then you shouldn't expect to turn up any further observables or basic entities that could occupy such a region, because this would increase the number of possible states for such a region beyond the Bekenstein bound.